# 500 Internal Server Error after remove addon Odoo V8

Tags: amazon-web-services, odoo, odoo-8, bitnami

I uninstalled an addon by mistake and has caused me an internal server error, the log file reads:

```
2016-01-07 00:26:27,355 8253 CRITICAL bitnami_openerp openerp.service.server: Failed to initialize database `bitnami_openerp`.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg/openerp/service/server.py", line 919, in preload_registries
registry = RegistryManager.new(dbname, update_module=update_module)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 368, in new
openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 357, in load_modules
registry.setup_models(cr)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 192, in setup_models
model._setup_fields(cr, SUPERUSER_ID)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg/openerp/api.py", line 336, in old_api
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg/openerp/models.py", line 2987, in _setup_fields
field.setup(self.env)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg/openerp/fields.py", line 453, in setup
self._setup_related(env)
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg/openerp/fields.py", line 499, in _setup_related
field = recs._fields[name]
KeyError: 'formated_vat'
```

It would be great if you could help me, please.

Comment: It looks like only a database was removed, but the actual addon is still active (and unable to open the database).

Comment: @DawidFerenczy I removed the addon and all the addons that depend on it, but the problem persists.

Comment: Do you think it's properly uninstalled, if for example this file is executed: `/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg/openerp/service/server.py`?

Comment: BTW 30 seconds of googling: https://bitnami.com/forums/forums/general/topics/uninstall (first reply, second paragraph).